# regex_replace is returning empty string

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to remove all characters that are not digit, dot (.), plus/minus sign (+/-) with empty character/string for float conversion.
When I pass my string through regex_replace function I am returned an empty string.
I belive something is wrong with my regex expression `std::regex reg_exp("\\D|[^+-.]")`
Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string temporary_recieve_data = "    S S   +456.789 tg\r\n";
    std::string::size_type  sz;
    const std::regex        reg_exp("\\D|[^+-.]");   // matches not digit, decimal point (.), plus sign, minus sign
    std::string             numeric_string = std::regex_replace(temporary_recieve_data, reg_exp, ""); //replace the character that are not digit, dot (.), plus-minus sign (+,-) with empty character/string for float conversion
    std::cout << "Numeric String : " << numeric_string << std::endl;
    if (numeric_string.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    float           data_value = std::stof(numeric_string, &sz);
    std::cout << "Float Value : " << data_value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

I have been trying to evaluate my regex expression on regex101.com for past 2 days but I am unable to figure out where I am wrong with my regular expression. When I just put \D, the editor substitutes non-digit character properly but soon as I add or condition `|` for not dot `.` or plus `+` or minus `-` sign the editor returns empty string.

Comment: I recommend you use something like https://regex101.com to test your reqular expression first.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have been trying to evaluate my regex expression on https://regex101.com/ for past 2 days but I am unable to figure out where I am wrong with my regular expression. When I just put `\D`, the editor substitutes non-digit character properly but soon as I add or condition for dot (.) or plus or minus sign the editor returns empty string.

Comment: This approach is prone to problems (or at least results many find surprising). For example, I'd find it somewhat surprising when `1abd2` converted to `12`. Fine to ignore the `abc`, but probably not usually so good to take things that had previously been separate, and mash them together into a single number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is empty because [your regex matches each character](https://regex101.com/r/e7R0cW/1).

- [`\D`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars) already matches every character that is *not a digit*.
  So plus, hyphen and the period thus far are consumed.
  And digits get consumed by the [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): `[^+-.]`
- Further the hyphen indicates a range inside a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
  Either escape it or put it at the start or end of the char-class.
  (funnily the used range [`+-.`](https://regex101.com/r/CW5A5t/1) [43-46](https://www.asciitable.com/) even contained a hyphen)

Remove the alternation with `\D` and put `\d` into the *negated class*:

```
[^\d.+-]+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YOwMQK/1) (attaching [`+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for *one or more* is efficient)